# DD4T site set up issue | SDLWEB8 | could not load the source in VS2013

Tags: dd4t, web8

i am trying to setup DD4T site on sdlweb8 i have installed DD4T templates 2.0.7 on web8 from blow link which is working fine

```
https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.TridionTemplates/releases
```

i have also downloaded the DD4T 2.0.7 source code from same link as given above.
but once i open the solution in VS2013 its unable to load the project getting error in attached screenshort.

[image]

Comment: Check step 3 from this answer: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/13186/73

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smondal/archive/2015/08/24/the-imported-project-quot-c-program-files-x86-msbuild-microsoft-windowsxaml-v14-0-8-1-microsoft-windows-ui-xaml-csharp-targets-quot-was-not-found.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Meyank, Error message is showing, DD4T templating solution is searching for MSBuild at default installation path. Installation and integration of MSBuild with Visual studio will fix your error.

As mentioned in the post suggested by Albert Romkes, You can download the MSBuild from path https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/releases.