# DD4T 2.0 Templating ILMerge Issue "Unresolved assembly reference not allowed"

Tags: templating, template-building-blocks, dd4t-2

I want to upgrade my existing custom TBBS to use DD4T 2.0 from DD4T 1 and uploaded the following into my Nuget feed:

1. `DD4T.Core.2.1.0`
2. `DD4T.Model.2.1.0`
3. `DD4T.Templates.Base.2.1.2`
4. `Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.8`

I am referring those in my `ms-build` commands to merge those dlls alongwith TBBs to get a `Templating.merged.dll` which I want to upload to my CMS.

The issue what I am facing is as soon as I point to `DD4T.Templates.Base` DLL which is there in DD4T 2.0 my merged DLL shows 0 bytes.

All other DD4T 2.0 DLLs are fine with merging except `DD4T.Templates.Base` DLL. I checked the build window and it shows:

> Unresolved assembly reference not allowed

For the DLLs like `Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary V2` etc. I am adding those in the `ms-build` merge one by one but not sure how many I need to add. Currently I am stuck with the error `Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainLibrary` and I did not find this in ECL list.

Please suggest the best way to deal with this.

Comment: Please refer this post - http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13185/dd4t-generate-dd4t-templates-merged-dll-using-ilmerge-manually - for a detailed step by step approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project files of the latest DD4T Templates release (https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.TridionTemplates/blob/master/source/DD4T.Templates/DD4T.Templates.csproj and https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.TridionTemplates/blob/master/source/DD4T.Templates.Base/DD4T.Templates.Base.csproj) show us the following dependencies from SDL Tridion 2013 SP1:

- `Tridion.Common.dll`
- `Tridion.ContentManager.Common.dll`
- `Tridion.ContentManager.dll`
- `Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.dll`
- `Tridion.ContentManager.Queuing.dll`
- `Tridion.ContentManager.TemplateTypes.dll`
- `Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.dll`
- `Tridion.ContentManager.TypeRegistration.dll`
- `Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.dll`
- `Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.V2.dll`
- `Tridion.Logging.dll`

the following from DD4T 2.1.0:

- `DD4T.ContentModel.dll`
- `DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts.dll`
- `DD4T.ContentModel.XmlSerializers.dll`
- `DD4T.Serialization.dll`

plus Newtonsoft Json 6.0.8:

- `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`

The SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 files referenced can all be found in the `..\Tridion\bin\client` folder on the server you installed the SDL Tridion Content Manager on. You can't find these files anywhere else, you have to get them from an installed server. The DD4T DLLs you can get from NuGet or build yourself and the Newtonsoft DLL you can also get from NuGet.