# Install DD4T templates for Tridion Sites 9.5

Tags: dd4t, sites-9.5

Do we have setup instructions as what project(s) need to be downloaded for compiling dd4t.merged.dll so that this can be uploaded into Tridion CMS 9.5

we got older version which I believe followed something similar like
[DD4T - Generate DD4T.Templates.merged.dll using ILMerge manually](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13185/dd4t-generate-dd4t-templates-merged-dll-using-ilmerge-manually)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the latest version of the DD4T templates without modifying any code (as I would recommend), you can simply download the latest (2.5) release here: https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.TridionTemplates/releases. The templates work with Tridion 9.5.

If you want to build a custom set of DD4T-compatible templates, just reference the latest release of the DD4T.Templates.Base Nuget package and create one or more classes extending BasePageTemplate or BaseComponentTemplate. Use ilmerge (e.g. in a post-build action) to create a merged DLL, which you can upload to Tridion using TcmUploadAssembly.exe. The instructions in [DD4T - Generate DD4T.Templates.merged.dll using ILMerge manually](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13185/dd4t-generate-dd4t-templates-merged-dll-using-ilmerge-manually) are still valid.

Comment: Good Morning Quirijn


Thank you. We did customization before. So we cannot uplaod merged.dll as-is.


for example, DD4T.Utils\Resolver\DefaultLinkResolver.cs was updated last time.

Sorry for all caps below.

we got 
       DD4T.CONTENTMODEL,
       DD4T.CONTENTMODEL.CONTRACTS,
       DD4T.CORECONTRACTS
       DD4T.FACTORIES
       DD4T.PROVIDERS.SDLTRIDION2013SP1
       DD4T.UTILS
       DD4T.VIEWMODELS

PLUS

   SDL.WEB.COMMMON (STARTUP PROJECT)
   SDL.WEB.MVC
   SDL.WEB.TRIDION

How do we get all of these updated?


Kind Regards,

Comment: First, remove all your current references to any DD4T or SDL or Tridion DLL. Then add a reference to the DD4T.Templates.Base package version 2.5.0. This will give you all the DLLs you need. Follow the instructions in the other question to find out which DLLs you need to merge. Definitely do NOT merge any SDL DLLs!