# DD4T get children from OrganizationalItem

Tags: 2011, dd4t

From a DD4T project, I'm trying to get the children from an OrganizationalItem but the object doesn't have that property. I'm runing a MVC project and I'm trying to get the page from the controller on the web application.

```
public class NavigationService
{    
    private readonly IPageFactory _pageFactory;

    public NavigationService(IpageFactory pagefactory)
    {
        _pageFactory = pageFactory;
    }
    private void GetPagesFromStructureGroup(NavigationItem navItem)
    {
        if (!_pageFactory.TryGetPage(navItem.Tcm, out var StructureGroup))
            return null;
        var structureGroup = StructureGroup.StructureGroup;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain in a bit more detail clearly, what are trying to do, are you trying this on the CM side or web app side?

Comment: The StructureGroup object does not exist in the Delivery side, it's a Content Manager only object. I think you may need to rethink the solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get a list of children of an organizational item (folder, structuregroup) in DD4T. This is because this is not possible on the content delivery side of Tridion at all.

I would recommend writing a custom DD4T page template to achieve this. See [Install DD4T templates for Tridion Sites 9.5](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/21651/install-dd4t-templates-for-tridion-sites-9-5) for more information.